# How can I convert a ResponseEntity to List

Tags: java, rest, response

I have this code below:

```
ResponseEntity<Users[]> users = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Users[].class);
List<ResponseEntity<Users[]>> usersList = Arrays.asList(users);
    
for(ResponseEntity<Users[]> user : usersList) { 
        
    //Users[] user = users.getBody();
    System.out.println(users.getBody()[0]);
}
```

Above I have a list of ResponseEntity with just one ResponseEntity object, and inside this object I have a vector of Users object.

How can I convert this list of ResponseEntity to just a list of Users?

Comment: Why are you putting the ResponseEntity with the users inside a new Array? If you're getting the response body from your `users` you already got what you want, right?

Comment: But I would like to retrieve a list of Users and not a vector of Users.

Comment: How can I fix this code to return a list of Users:

ResponseEntity<Users[]> users = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Users[].class);

?

Comment: Just use `Arrays.asList(...)` on the response body of your entity.

Comment: Try `List<Users> usersList = Arrays.asList(users.getBody());`.

Comment: It´s works!

Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think,you can do something like below :

```
UserList response = restTemplate.getForObject(url,UserList.class);
List<User> users= response.getUsers();

And

public class UserList {
    private List<User> users;

  //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: this way above wasn´t work. I got the error:

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 null

I think it´s because I have to authenticate to get the request successfully. I think I have to pass the requestEntity in:

ResponseEntity<User[]> users = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, User[].class);